# How can I improve the precision of a program that writes a message to kmsg?

Tags: linux, rust, time

I want to celebrate the ten millionth second of uptime on a server, so I figured that writing a message that has `10000000.000000` as its `dmesg` timestamp would be pretty cool. I quickly hacked together a program that calculates when it should write the message to `/dev/kmsg` to get the desired timestamp. [GitHub link since it's not very short](https://github.com/adamski234/kmsg-precise-writer) Unfortunately, I am not able to get past the 100 μs precision barrier. The closest the program has gotten is 4 μs, with an average deviation of 50 μs. Are there any other techniques that I could use to improve that?

What I've tried so far:
Printing `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` times to `/dev/kmsg` and then comparing what it has printed with the included timestamp to calculate how much earlier it needs to start writing
Running a short (currently 20 rounds) warmup of writing messages, since I noticed that the first few writes were far slower than the others

Comment: Do you think the OS has more precision than this in its uptime variable?

Comment: It's not just about the precision of the clock itself. There's also properly scheduling your actions in time and minimizing random jitter. Which is the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: That seems impossible. Unless you have a real-time OS, there's no way to predict delays added by the scheduler.

Comment: That is something I *tried* to anticipate: it runs on a system with very little load, using `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO`, restricted to a single CPU. However, none of this seems to have had much of an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Linux provides several high-resolution timers, such as the High-Resolution Timer (HRT) and the POSIX timers. HRTs is a hardware based timer and is available on modern CPUs. These timers have a higher resolution than the system clock and can provide time with nanosecond precision.

Example: [Rust interface to Linux's TimerFD API](https://docs.rs/timerfd/1.4.1/timerfd/)

> The Linux kernel's timerfd API provides timer functionality with a
> high degree of precision. The resolution of the timer depends on the
> clock source that is used to create the timer. The timerfd API
> supports a number of different clock sources, including
> CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, and CLOCK_REALTIME. The
> CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock source has a resolution of nanoseconds, for example.

```rust
// Example from timerfd = "1.4.1"

use timerfd::{TimerFd, TimerState, SetTimeFlags};
use std::time::Duration;

// Create a new timerfd
// (unwrap is actually fine here for most usecases)
let mut tfd = TimerFd::new().unwrap();

// The timer is initially disarmed
assert_eq!(tfd.get_state(), TimerState::Disarmed);

// Set the timer
tfd.set_state(TimerState::Oneshot(Duration::new(1, 0)), SetTimeFlags::Default);

// Observe that the timer is now set
match tfd.get_state() {
    TimerState::Oneshot(d) => println!("Remaining: {:?}", d),
    _ => unreachable!(),
}

// Wait for the remaining time
tfd.read();

// It was a oneshot timer, so it's now disarmed
assert_eq!(tfd.get_state(), TimerState::Disarmed);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, clock resolution was not the limiting factor. Actually writing to the `/dev/kmsg` file was really inconsistent with how long it took.